# How to Fetch Data to Modal Bootstrap Using Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, bootstrap-4

I have one page that display list of the item from databse. I want  to open the item detail with bootstrap modal through jquery. I know ajax in running to success as it throws alerts. But cannot open modal.
Can you please show me the wrong code ? thank you

These are my code :

This is the Model

```
function get_detail_item($id){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('item', 'purchase');
    $this->db->join('purchase', 'purchase.id=item.id_purchase', 'inner');
    $this->db->join('status', 'status.id=item.id_status', 'inner');
    $this->db->join('category', 'category.id=item.id_category', 'inner');
    $this->db->where('item.id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row();
}
```

This is the Controller

```
 function detail_item($id){
    $this->load->model('item_model');
    $data = $this->item_model->get_detail_item($id);
    echo json_encode($data);

}
```

This is the Button

```
<a href="#Item_Detail" class="btn btn-outline-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Item_Detail" data-id="<?php echo $row->id?>">Detail</a>
```

This is the Modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="Item_Detail" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Detail Item</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p id="proName"></p>
            <p id="proRoom"></p>
            <p id="proBuilding"></p>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the Ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#Item_Detail').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var productID= $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
    $.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo base_url().'admin/detail_item/'?>/" + productID,
        method: "GET",
        dataType:"JSON",
        success:function(data)
        {
            $('#proName').val(data.name_item);
            $('#proRoom').val(data.room);
            $('#proBuilding').val(data.building);

        }
    })
});
```

Comment: did you make sure that `productID` is not empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with this code for your model:

```
function get_detail_item($id){
    //I do not know if you will have get conflicts with select columns because of the same names
    $this->db->join('purchase', 'purchase.id=item.id_purchase', 'inner');
    $this->db->join('status', 'status.id=item.id_status', 'inner');
    $this->db->join('category', 'category.id=item.id_category', 'inner');
    $this->db->where('item.id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get('item');
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

The button:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-info js-detail" data-id="<?php echo $row->id?>">Detail</a>
```

Please, the controller keeps with echo and json_encode. And the ajax call, like that:

```
//It good practice to use a delegate event, but you choose it
$('.js-detail').on('click', function(){
var id =  $(this).data('id');
console.log("ID: " +id);
 $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/admin/detail_item/'+id,
      success:function(data)
        {
            var result = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(result);
            $('#proName').text(result.name_item);
            $('#proRoom').text(result.room);
            $('#proBuilding').text(result.building);
            $('#Item_Detail').modal('show');

        }
        error: function (data) {
         alert("error");
      }
    });
});
```

Please, see the console log to results ajax and possible errors during execution.

Comment: I edited my response because I see you are doing some wrong in some cases. Please, test again with the new changes. Thanks

Comment: i just paste your syntax. But it same doesn;t show the result of console.log

Comment: it empty when i try

Comment: Are you sure the js is not caching? Because console.log("ID:"+id) at least should be shown it.
See the console -> network and url if it is sending data.

Comment: Debug your result model too

Comment: the model result the data : string(687) "{"id":"1","name_item":"PC INKJET 1","room":"pipe &amp; prec","building":"scg","id_purchase":"11195","id_status":"2","id_category":"1","id_damage":"0","id_borrow":"0","id_return":"0","qr_code":"111.png","who_purchase":"dadang","date_purchase":"2019-07-

Comment: but i dont know why it can't parsing the data to my modal

Comment: no, the console.log doesn;t show up. In the tab network the data is not appeared. looks like it doen't load the data

Comment: Thanks jlosada. I change it using the new method and the data is appear in the modal

Comment: Great! Please, remember check this answer as solution to help other people. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Write this on success

```
success:function(data)
        {
          $('#Item_Detail').modal('show')
            $('#proName').text('').text(data.name_item);
            $('#proRoom').text('').text(data.room);
            $('#proBuilding').text('').text(data.building);

        }
```

and change function return not echo

```
 function detail_item($id){
    $this->load->model('item_model');
    $data = $this->item_model->get_detail_item($id);
    return $data;

}
```

Comment: if this help you, plz  accept the answer to help others

Comment: You mean like this :success:function(data)
            {
                $('#proName').val(data.name_item);
                $('#proRoom').val(data.room);
                $('#proBuilding').val(data.building);
                $('#Item_Detail').modal('show'); }

Comment: but it didn't work. the modal doesn't show the data

Comment: See my code ,i updated it , you  shouldnot use val,
you should use append or text,val use with inputs

Comment: You used it with text or append?

Comment: Samee didn't work too. Did i made mistake in the controllers and others too ?

Comment: i use with text

Comment: write console.log(data) see if there is data in your console on success

Comment: the data doesn't load when i write console.log . But if i console.log in controller function, the json data look appear

Comment: what do you mean by console.log in controller function??

Comment: function detail_item($id){
    $this->load->model('item_model');
    $data = $this->item_model->get_detail_item($id);
    echo json_encode($data); die(var_dump($data));

}

Comment: You should use return not echo in function detail_item($id)
See my answer , i updated it!

Comment: doesn't load too

Comment: it made me confuse for 3 hours

Comment: You should write return instead of echo write console.log(data) in your success function..
and check if the request successfully done in network devtools without errors!

Comment: exactly it return the data like this : string(687) "{"id":"1","name_item":"PC INKJET 1","room":"pipe &amp; prec","building":"scg","id_purchase":"11195","id_status":"2","id_category":"1","id_damage":"0","id_borrow":"0","id_return":"0","qr_code":"111.png","who_purchase":"dadang","date_purchase":"2019-07-11","price":"33","who_received":"suryadi","date_received":"2019-07-31","range_shrinked":"4","status_item":"Use","description_status":"It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. ","category_item":"Personal Computer

Comment: but in the modal doesn't appear

Comment: Thanks mohammed. I change it using the new method and the data is appear in the modal